# при просмотре через gulp browser-sync не видит script в node_modules

Tags: angularjs, gulp, npm, browsersync

Вот структура

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот таск галп

```html
gulp.task('serve', ['sass', 'js'], function () {
    browserSync.init({
        server: 'app'
    });

    gulp.watch(['app/src/sass/**'], ['sass']);
    gulp.watch('app/src/js/*.js', ['js-watch']);
    gulp.watch('app/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);

});

gulp.task('default', ['serve'], function () {
    console.log('gulp is watching...')
});
```

Если через script подключать angularjs в index.html

```html
<script src="../node_modules/angularjs-ie8-build/dist/angular.min.js"></script>
```

то при загрузке через browser-sync angular не определен
Путь правильный, не через б.с. работает

Answer (score 1):

Browser-sync смотрит только за одной папкой, и как бы окружает ее, выйти за пределы папки нельзя. Вам нужно этот скрипт закидывать в папку app.
Для этого создайте таск который берет этот скрипт из node_modules и склеивает их с остальные скриптами, если ваш таск по js выполнял такого рода действия, или же просто закидывайте этот файл в нужную вам папку в app через таск или же вручную.